# Changing the font size in AppCode

Tags: appcode

I'm using Appcode and I would like to change the font size though I can't seem to find any option to do this (nor does there seem to be much help on the internet).

If I go to Preferences->Editor->Colors&Fonts->Font I can see a font size, though it is not editable.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the font size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to "Save as..." your custom settings at first (for example as "MyFonts"). After that the field becomes writable.